# ¿Como recolecto los datos de 3 tablas en 1 ArrayList?

Tags: java

Quiero recojer los datos en un Boton de 3 tablas diferentes para poder visualizarlas en un reporte jasper, lo he hecho para 1 sola y todo bien pero no encuentro la forma para que en el JRBeanCollectionDataSource me jale la info de las 3 tablas, estoy haciendolo en JAVA, no se si lo este haciendo bien.

```
            List<ProductoReportGral> listaProductos = new ArrayList<ProductoReportGral>();

            int filas= tbfacturas.getRowCount();
             int fila=tbfacturas1.getRowCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)

            {
                ProductoReportGral p = new  ProductoReportGral(tbfacturas.getValueAt(i, 2).toString(),tbfacturas.getValueAt(i, 4).toString(),tbfacturas.getValueAt(i, 3).toString(),tbfacturas.getValueAt(i, 5).toString());
                listaProductos.add(p);
              }          
            for (int i = 0; i < fila; i++)
            {
                ProductoReportGral p = new  ProductoReportGral(tbfacturas1.getValueAt(i, 2).toString(),tbfacturas1.getValueAt(i, 4).toString(),tbfacturas1.getValueAt(i, 3).toString(),tbfacturas1.getValueAt(i, 5).toString());
                listaProductos.add(p);
            }
            List<gastosGRAL> listaProducto = new ArrayList<gastosGRAL>();

            int fil= tbproductos.getRowCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < fil; i++)
            {
                gastosGRAL p = new  gastosGRAL(tbproductos.getValueAt(i, 2).toString(),tbproductos.getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
                listaProducto.add(p);
            }
            try {       
    Map parametro = new HashMap();
    parametro.put("Fec_Ini", jDateChooser1.getDate());
    parametro.put("Fec_fin", jDateChooser2.getDate());
    parametro.put("totalFac", txttotal.getText());
    parametro.put("totalshelo", txttotal2.getText());
    parametro.put("totalgastos", txttotal1.getText());                  
  //JasperReport  reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);
  JasperReport reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource("/Formulario/ReporteVenta.jasper"));
    JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametro, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaProductos));      
    JasperPrint jprints = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametro, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaProducto)); 
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jprint, false);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jprints, false);
} catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConsultasDetallesFacturas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO! En primer lugar, deberías explicar qué problema te estás encontrando con este código, no simplemente decir "no sé si lo hago bien" ¿Funciona? Si no ¿cuál es el fallo? Si funciona ¿cuál es el problema (lento, etc...)? Revisa [ask] y [help]

Comment: En segundo lugar te recomiendo encarecidamente que uses **nombresDescriptivos** en tus variables, mejorará mucho la legibilidad de tu código. Por ejemplo usas "filas" para el número de filas de "tbfacturas", y "fila" para el número de filas de "tbfacturas1", y "fil" para el número de filas de tbProductos. ¿Por qué no "filasFacturas", "filasFacturas1", "filasProductos"?

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios, en este caso al ejecutar no funciona por que no me reconoce las columnas de la tabla productos ya que lo estoy poniendo en un segundo  JRBeanCollectionDataSource y solo me lee el primero, si solo arrojo un  array para una sola tabla me funciona sin ningun problema